# Just cannot figure out how to reloadData in UITableView using a navigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

This is my first time asking a question & posting code so I hope I have included everything that is necessary.

In several of my other apps I have been able to successfully reloadData in a UITableView but for some reason I cannot get it to work here.

I am using a navigationController and drilling down a few levels in the UITableView until a new class loads which right now just has two buttons that switch between 2 similar plist files so I can tell that the tableView is actually reloading (Data.plist & Data2.plist)

This is eventually going to be a timesheet sort of app where individual jobs are listed and the user (driver) will punch a timeclock with In/Out buttons. For now, what I want is to drill down and click the button that loads the other plist and go back up to reveal that the new plist data has loaded. My problem is that I cannot get the tableView to reload at all. I've tried putting different variations of [self.tableView reloadData] & [myTableView reloadData] (which I have also connected via IB) all over the place but none of them work. I'm currently calling a method in the rootViewController (where the tableView is) from detailViewController (where the buttons are) and that basic process works for me in other apps when there is no navigationController being used. The navigationController seems to be throwing me off here in this app. I hope an easy solution can be found. My code so far looks like this:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //THIS ESTABLISHES WHICH PLIST TO LOAD BASED ON THE BUTTON CLICKED
    plistToUse = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"plistToUse"];
    if (plistToUse == @"Data.plist") {
        NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
        self.data = tempDict;
        [tempDict release];
    } else if (plistToUse == @"Data2.plist") {
        NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data2.plist"];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
        self.data = tempDict;
        [tempDict release];
    } else  {
        NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
        self.data = tempDict;
        [tempDict release];
    }

    if(CurrentLevel == 0) {            
        NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
        [tempArray release];            
        self.tableDataSource = [self.data objectForKey:@"Rows"];            
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Choose Driver";
    } else if (CurrentLevel == 1) {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Choose Day";
    } else if (CurrentLevel == 2) {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Choose Job";
    } else if (CurrentLevel == 3) {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Job Details";
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;
    }         
}


-(void)update {
    dvController.labelHelper.text = @"UPDATED"; //USED TO SEE IF A LABEL IN THE BUTTON CLASS WILL UPDATE        
    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
    [tempArray release];        
    self.tableDataSource = [self.data objectForKey:@"Rows"];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"Choose Driver";
    self.navigationController.title = @"THE TITLE";        
    [myTableView reloadData];    
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    unsortedIndex=1;
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.tableDataSource count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];
    if ([Children count] == 0) {
        Titles = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
        in1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"InTime1"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", in1];
    }
    in1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"InTime1"];
    out1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OutTime1"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", in1, out1];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    if([Children count] == 0) {     
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        dvController.labelSiteName.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Company"];
        dvController.labelSiteAddress.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Address"];
        dvController.labelSiteNotes.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Notes"];
        [dvController.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [dvController.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [dvController.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        dvController.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        [dvController release];
    }
    else {        
        RootViewController *rvController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;
        rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
        rvController.tableDataSource = Children;
        [rvController release];
    }

}
```

DetailViewController.m
These are the two buttons that should reload the tableView with either Data.plist or Data2.plist

```
-(IBAction)getInTime1:(id)sender {   
    plistToUse = @"Data.plist";
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:plistToUse forKey:@"plistToUse"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [rvController update];
}


-(IBAction)getOutTime1:(id)sender {
    plistToUse = @"Data2.plist";
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:plistToUse forKey:@"plistToUse"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [rvController update];
}
```

I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: is RootViewController a UITableView subclass?

Comment: @Monty is your table doesn't show for the first time itself..? and check whether your `delegate` & `dataSource` of `tableView` are linked to your File's Owner..

Comment: I'm basically using the same setup as if you created a new Master Detail project in Xcode (I'm using 4.5).

Comment: Yes, the table view does load the first time using Data.plist. I cannot get it to reloadData so it displays Data2.plist

Answer (score 1):

Add your data fetching from `plist` code into your `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` methods, so that each time view appears, the data is loaded from plist.

And also note that your arrays are allocated only once.

This will work for you.